# crossdomain.xml doesn't give my Java applet access

Tags: java, security, safari, applet, crossdomain.xml

I have a Java applet on my site that interacts with my server such that I need a crossdomain.xml file to allow permission.  I've gotten around this by running my code inside a doPrivileged() block.  However, on Safari, it doesn't work without a crossdomain.xml file.  So I made one, and here it is:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
  <cross-domain-policy>
       <allow-access-from domain="*" /> 
  </cross-domain-policy>
```

It works fine.  The problem is that due to security issues, I can't allow access from anywhere.  I tried this:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
  <cross-domain-policy>
       <allow-access-from domain="*.mydomain.com" /> 
  </cross-domain-policy>
```

But that doesn't work: my applet doesn't get the right privileges when running in Safari.  Why does this not work?  Is my applet running from a different domain that I need to include?  How do I find out which one it is?

My applet is just trying to get an output stream from a URLConnection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access from specific domains is not supported. See the [Plug-In 2 page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/plugin2-142482.html#CROSSDOMAINXML).